# testing angularJS application using jasmine plugin failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am learning to write test cases for my angularJS application. As a newbie, trying to find some sample examples working demo.
The below example i found online is using Jasmine plugin to test angularJS application, but the application seems not to be working.

[Click here for demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/8Mr99k/)

```
    <html ng-app="testingApp">

  <head>
    <!-- Add Jasmine -->
    <script data-require="jasmine@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <!-- Jasmine html & css for reporting -->
    <link data-require="jasmine@*" data-semver="2.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.css" />
    <script data-require="jasmine@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jasmine@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
    <!-- Add AngularJS -->
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.25" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- AngularJS testing helpers -->
    <script data-require="angular-mocks@*" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="calculatorController as vm">
    <!-- display our message from the controller -->
    <h1>{{vm.message}}</h1>
    <!-- Setup number inputs and a button for our calculator -->
    <form>
      <input id="firstNumber" type="number" ng-model="vm.firstNumber" />
      <span>+</span>
      <input id="secondNumber" type="number" ng-model="vm.secondNumber" />
      <button ng-click="vm.addNumber()">Do it</button>
    </form>
    <!-- Display the result -->
    <span>{{vm.result}}</span>
    <!-- This is our Angular app, keeping it simple -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      angular
        .module('testingApp',[])
        .controller('calculatorController', calculatorController);

        function calculatorController(){
          var vm = this;
          vm.message = 'I am a simple calculator';
          vm.result = 0;
          vm.firstNumber = 0;
          vm.secondNumber = 0;
          vm.addNumber = addNumber;

          function addNumber(){
            vm.result = vm.firstNumber + vm.secondNumber;
          }

        };
    </script>
    <!-- This is our test spec -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

      describe("Unit: calculatorController tests", function() {

        // setup code for testing this unit
        var controller;
        beforeEach(function(){
          module('testingApp');

          inject(function ($controller){
            controller = $controller('calculatorController');  
          });

        });

        it("PASSING TEST - should be able to display a title", function() {
          expect(controller.message).toBe('I am a simple calculator');
        });

        it("FAILING TEST - should be able to display a title", function() {
          expect(controller.message).toBe('fail fail fail');
        });

        it("PASSING TEST - should add 2+2 and get result of 4", function() {
          controller.firstNumber = 2;
          controller.secondNumber = 2;
          controller.result = 0;
          controller.addNumber()
          expect(controller.result).toEqual(4);
        });

      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions to make this example work would be very helpful.
Also please suggest any good example links using jasmine,karma or any testing plugins for angularJS application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below test case causing failure.

```
 it("FAILING TEST - should be able to display a title", function() {
              expect(controller.message).toBe('fail fail fail');
 });
```

This test case should be like this because you want to test negative case

```
it("FAILING TEST - should be able to display a title", function() {
          expect(controller.message).not.toBe('fail fail fail');
});
```

If you want to pass the test case without negative test.Use `.not.toBe`

```
controller.message='fail fail fail';
    it("FAILING TEST - should be able to display a title", function() {

                     expect(controller.message).toBe('fail fail fail');
         });
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pc77NrIsPyAjl8AtcCNP?p=preview)

Comment: thankyou. In the plunker, the testcase  it("PASSING TEST - should add 2+2 and get result of 4", function() {.. is not getting executed. Is there any issue with that test case and when i entered values in textboxes and click on Do it, its not executing the test case either..

Comment: Sorry , correct me if i'm wrong. When i type some numbers and click on Do IT button in the plunker nothing happens. How to test the follwong test case scenario ?  it("PASSING TEST - should add 2+2 and get result of 4", function() {..

Comment: @javaUser  you are tesing application where you can not test live data.You are mocking it.If you have such requirement then go for Protractor end to end testing.Its not possible with this approach

Comment: oh ok got it. Thankyou. I thought with jasmine or karma we can test live data too. So please correct me if i am wrong, if we use jasmine or karma plugin to test angularJS application, we can mock the data and test but not live data, correct?

Comment: yes.With jasmine plus karma(gulp or grunt) you can have mock data for testing business flow.if

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge. It helped me.